# interact only with some physics bodies and ignore others

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a player and I want to change its behavior regarding physics after it collects a PowerUp. When he collects the powerUp I still want him to be able to interact with the physics bodies of the coins, so he can still collect them. But I want him to ignore the physics Body of the Walls so he can fly through them.

I don't really want to set the physics body from the walls to nil because when the power Up runs off, I have to reattach the physics body to the walls again.

I guess there is some variable for the physics body I cant find right now.

Appreciate any help

Comment: thank you , i added the spriteKit tag

Answer (score 1):

Okay this question was pretty simple, you just have to set the collisionBitMask and the contactTestBitMask correctly

Comment: You do indeed. It sounds as though you need to disable collisions between the player and the walls whilst the coin's power-up effect is in use. Have you managed to do this?

Comment: You can also turn off `isDynamic` if you want collisions to work 1 way.